# Which CSS framework is compatible with AMP?

Tags: css

[AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) has many [limitations for CSS](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages) - it needs to be inlined, cannot exceed 50KB and cannot include `!important`, `filter`, nor JavaScript. Which CSS frameworks can be safely used with AMP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This is a community wiki, you can expand it if you have something to add.*

---

These CSS-only frameworks are compatible with AMP (sorted by size):

- [Mini.css](http://minicss.org/) (46KB minified)
- [AMP Spectre](https://niutech.github.io/amp-spectre/) (42KB minified)
- [AMP MUI](https://niutech.github.io/amp-mui/) (40KB minified)
- [Picnic CSS](https://picnicss.com/) (38KB minified)
- [AMP Surface](https://niutech.github.io/amp-surface/) (28KB minified)
- [Mustard UI](https://mustard-ui.com/) (24KB minified)
- [AMP Start](https://ampstart.com/) (23KB minified)
- [Pure CSS](https://purecss.io/) (16KB minified)
- [Milligram](http://milligram.io/) (9KB minified)
- [1BX](https://1bx.uk/) (9KB minified)
- [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) (6KB minified)
- [Tacit](http://yegor256.github.io/tacit/) (6KB minified)
- [Wing](https://kbrsh.github.io/wing/) (5KB minified)

In order to use one of them in an AMP HTML page, get the minified CSS file, remove any `!important` or `filter` if they exist, paste the inlined CSS code into `<style amp-custom>` inside `<head>` and replace any `<img>` with `<amp-img>` inside `<body>`.

Comment: Which of these are AMP compatible without any changes? Removing !important is going to break lots of these.

Comment: @DD These are: [AMP Spectre](https://niutech.github.io/amp-spectre/), [AMP Surface](https://niutech.github.io/amp-surface/), [AMP MUI](https://niutech.github.io/amp-mui/).

Comment: @DD Also [AMP Start](https://ampstart.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've created and released one called 1bx.uk that you can see here... https://1bx.uk

It's well documented and built specifically for AMP.

As we use it in our business, it will be well supported

Comment: **This site can’t be reached**

1bx.uk’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 1):

This framework is individually adaptable.

https://www.ampcssframework.com

Answer (score 1):

Amp CSS Framework is based on Bootstrap.

See here: https://ampcssframework.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing: http://basscss.com/v7/docs/guides/ui/

or as scss

https://github.com/basscss/basscss-sass

.. yes it not so active but might be interesting, the syntax seems short and simple, also independently reusable components

Comment: Thanks! The [minified CSS](https://unpkg.com/basscss@8.0.2/css/basscss.min.css) is 10KB, but in order to be compatible with AMP, you have to manually remove all `!important`.

Comment: [Please do not write link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). They will probably be removed.